# Transmitting raw bytes via HTTP

Tags: php, http, byte

I am making a product that requires modules to be loaded.
The current idea is to exchange some assymetric keys that will inform client and server about an AES (Rijndael) 256 bit key, and exchange the DLL module that way.  However, since the serverside is written in PHP I need an efficient way of transmitting the encrypted DLL bytes. The only solutions I've seen online so far is encoding the bytes with base64 or hex and doing it that way. Even though I am using a host that has unlimited bandwidth, I still think it's inefficient and a waste of good bandwidth. I was hoping some PHP experts could tell me whether there is a way to output raw bytes in an HTTP response.

Comment: Well, you always can do a post request holding the payload or open a raw socket connection and do whatever you want with it. But what I don't understand: _exchange the DLL module_? You want to send a library via network _and then execute it on the server_????

Comment: Apologies for my vagueness, here's the clarification: It's basically an anti-cracking measure.  The server (PHP) holds some modules written in C# for a product I'm selling. Once it verifies a valid license in PHP it encrypts the DLL with AES, and transmits it via HTTP to the C# "loader". The C# program then decrypts the bytes and loads them as a sort of plugin - if that also did not make sense, please leave another comment! :)  

What I'm wondering is: is there an easy way to make _forexample_ `echo` output a raw bytestream that my HttpClient in C# can read?

Comment: Sure, possible, classical case of 1980th attempt to protect "intellectual property". Times have changed. Release the modules, remove the annoying license check, make a transparent agreement with your customers who will appreciate that things are easy and working and you will earn the money for your work ;-) (just my 2 cents from 40 years of experience in the business)

Comment: This particular piece of software has a target audience of 20-25 year olds.  Morals are low, they will find a way to dump the modules and a release it for free, which will give me no reward for my work. I am afraid the old "trust the people" philosophy is not viable in 2017.

Comment: Actually openness and mutual trust have become common only recently, so it clearly is the newer philosophy compared to old fashioned style. But however you like. What I don't understand: why would one want to make business with customers one does not trust?

Comment: This particular product is a mass-market product (I have no control over who purchases it).  It is by no means malicious or has a malicious target audience, but it will have a steep pricepoint, with a great demand.  Not easily affordable, and in high demand is a perfect recipe for ""good samaritans"" dumping the code and releasing it for free to the public. I see where you are coming from, and I wish it was a viable option in this case, but I have to use cryptography here if I want a chance of even the slightest compensation for my work.

Comment: Whatever. If you insist in making something easy complex, sure. Why can't you simply send the encrypted library specifying a mime type `octet/stream` if this is about a _response_ to a http request?

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for! I will look into the octet/stream mime type - thank you so much! And nice discussion about the ethics of todays software product customers. If you leave a reply to this thread I will mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong! Ethics is one thing. I learned that I made better business by acting open and transparent. Using licenses will reduce your user base by a factor of 100 or much more. Rarely a good thing.

Comment: In this case, however, licenses are the only viable option as it's a paid (monthly subscription) product - being transparent would be damaging to the business model.

Comment: Sure. Rethink your business model I would reply. But I see that you are very firm in this issue ;-) Have fun!